# Unable to access purchases.subscriptions API from developer console

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I create IN app purchase for my product and I link google console application with androidpublisher consent

I am trying to call below API but its always fail

API to call :- https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/acknowledge?authuser=3

Error :-
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.",
"domain": "androidpublisher",
"reason": "projectNotLinked"
}
]
}
}

Comment: I am getting this with the API explorer but I can access it using the Android publisher Java library on a server.  Are you calling from the app or the server?

Comment: I have the service account set up, so it works on the server, but I don't see how to use a service account with the API explorer.

Comment: Did you go through all the steps for linking Google Cloud Pub/Sub to the Google Play Developer API? https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready